# How can I create an Index of a pdf generated as below?

Tags: section-titles

I have a pdf generated as below. Now I would like to create the **index** which should
be a page listing all the names of papers included, i.e. the names of **sections**, one row should be dedicated for each paper from the entire pdf. How could I achieve this ?
Preferably in **XeTeX.**

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}% MWE only

\pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{(\paperheight-2cm)/(\paperwidth-3cm)}% 1cm margin
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\delta}{\paperwidth-2cm-2*\scale*(\paperheight-3cm)-4mm}% 4mm fudge factor

 
\usepackage[footwidth=paper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{plain}




\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}

\robustify{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page} \ \roman{page}\ \texthebrew{\hebrewnumeral{\value{page}}}}

 

\newcommand\gettitle[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    local filename = kpse.find_file("#1", 'graphic/figure')
    doc = pdfe.open(filename)
    info = pdfe.getinfo(doc)
    title = info['Title']
    tex.print(title)
  }}

\begin{document}

%  \includepdf[scale=1.02, nup=2x1,pages=1-8,trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cmB]{sh1.pdf}

%pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,picturecommand={\put(.15\paperwidth,3.3cm){\thepage}}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}


  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,picturecommand={\put(.15\paperwidth,3.3cm){\thepage}}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,picturecommand={\put(.15\paperwidth,3.3cm){\thepage}}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you want to have something like a `list of documents` much alike the `list of tables` ?

Comment: @alchemist You're right. Just the name of each paper together with the page on which it begins. Shall I be more precise with this ? Please tell me or provide a MWE . I mean just a separate A4 page with the heading of `R0.pdf` `example-image-a4-numbered.pdf` and the rest of chapters included via `includepdf`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the additions to your code example. This produces a `list of documents` on a separate page like the `list of tables`.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}% MWE only

\pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{(\paperheight-2cm)/(\paperwidth-3cm)}% 1cm margin
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\delta}{\paperwidth-2cm-2*\scale*(\paperheight-3cm)-4mm}% 4mm fudge factor

\usepackage[footwidth=paper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}

\robustify{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page} \ \roman{page}\ \texthebrew{\hebrewnumeral{\value{page}}}}

% ======  added to the mwe code
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlistof[section]{pdfdoc}{lop}{List of documents}

\newcommand{\pdfdoc}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{pdfdoc}
    \addcontentsline{lop}{pdfdoc}{\protect\numberline{\thepdfdoc} \addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small \textcolor{blue}{#1}}\par}

\xpatchcmd{\listofpdfdoc}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
\cftsetindents{pdfdoc}{15mm}{10mm}

% ===== end of addition

\newcommand\gettitle[1]{%
    \directlua{%
    local filename = kpse.find_file("#1", 'graphic/figure')
    doc = pdfe.open(filename)
    info = pdfe.getinfo(doc)
    title = info['Title']
    tex.print(title)
    }}

\begin{document}
    
    %  \includepdf[scale=1.02, nup=2x1,pages=1-8,trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cmB]{sh1.pdf}
    
    %pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}

% ===== added to print list of documents
    \listofpdfdoc
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of documents}
% ===== 
    
    \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
    trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,picturecommand={\put(.15\paperwidth,3.3cm){\thepage}}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
    \addcontentsline{lop}{pdfdoc}{example-image-a4-numbered - 1} % <- puts document name into list of documents
    
    
    \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
    trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,picturecommand={\put(.15\paperwidth,3.3cm){\thepage}}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
    \addcontentsline{lop}{pdfdoc}{example-image-a4-numbered - 2}
    
    \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
    trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,picturecommand={\put(.15\paperwidth,3.3cm){\thepage}}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
    \addcontentsline{lop}{pdfdoc}{example-image-a4-numbered - 3} \phantom{end} % <- needed to add the last entry to the list of documents

\end{document}
```

**Note** the addition of `\phantom{end}` to the last entry. Somehow that is needed to get the last entry into the list in your code. In my own document using the code to get a list of included documents that was not needed.

[image: pdf_lop_list]

Comment: Your answer is good but not exactly what I wanted. Instead of `\addcontentsline{lop}{pdfdoc}{example-image-a4-numbered - 2` I wanted that XeTeX itself **automatically** extracted the title from the file `{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}` instead of my coding it by hand. Please is that possible ?

Comment: And please note that everything is and should be in XeLaTeX .

Comment: I used LuaLaTeX compiling the example, so it should be compatible with XeLaTeX. As for that automatically part of your question ... that is beyond my knowledge of TeX and programming. A piece of coding in `Lua` might be possible, si I hope someone else can help you with that part.

Comment: I'm posting a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676742/how-can-i-automatically-create-an-index-of-a-pdf-generated-as-below). Anyway I do not think that XeLaTeX would compile Lua. I've tried but it does not.

Comment: No, XeTeX won't compile Lua, but you can switch to a LuaLaTeX compiler easily when using XeTeX. Just try compiling your document using LuaLaTeX and see if there are issues emerging.

Comment: This issue has appeared: ! I can't write on file `mergeSR.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output: 
! I can't write on file `mergeSR.pdf'.

Comment: That sounds like another program is blocking access to that file. It occurs for example when you have an older version of the file open in an external PDF reader and want to recompile the same file again in a TeX engine. It doesn;t look like a LuaLaTeX related issue.