# How can I **automatically** create an Index of a pdf generated as below?

Tags: xetex, pdf, section-titles

I have posted a similar question [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676714/how-can-i-create-an-index-of-a-pdf-generated-as-below)

**but** the answer there has a serious drawback, it must be **manually** inserted the section names,
while my dream was that it should be **fully automatically generated** from the `R0.pdf` files
which are present in the same CWD.
And everything should be in **XeLaTeX**

Here I just restate my original question:

I have a pdf generated as below. Now I would like to create the **index** which should
be a page listing all the names of papers included, i.e. the names of **sections**, one row should be dedicated for each paper from the entire pdf. How could I achieve this ?
Preferably in **XeTeX.**

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}% MWE only

\pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{(\paperheight-2cm)/(\paperwidth-3cm)}% 1cm margin
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\delta}{\paperwidth-2cm-2*\scale*(\paperheight-3cm)-4mm}% 4mm fudge factor

 
\usepackage[footwidth=paper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{plain}




\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}

\robustify{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page} \ \roman{page}\ \texthebrew{\hebrewnumeral{\value{page}}}}

 

\newcommand\gettitle[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    local filename = kpse.find_file("#1", 'graphic/figure')
    doc = pdfe.open(filename)
    info = pdfe.getinfo(doc)
    title = info['Title']
    tex.print(title)
  }}

\begin{document}

%  \includepdf[scale=1.02, nup=2x1,pages=1-8,trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cmB]{sh1.pdf}

%pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,picturecommand={\put(.15\paperwidth,3.3cm){\thepage}}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}


  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,picturecommand={\put(.15\paperwidth,3.3cm){\thepage}}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,picturecommand={\put(.15\paperwidth,3.3cm){\thepage}}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Were the included pdfs generated by Xe(La)TeX?  Do you have the .toc file for them?

Comment: No I don't have any files beyond something like this `https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.11202.pdf` and they were downloaded mostly from `ArXive.org`. Can I create these necessary `.toc` somehow ?

Comment: You can get the source of what was uploaded from https://arxiv.org/format/2012.11202.  That likely has the tex file, which would create the toc file.  Are you able to get tex source files for all of your pdfs?

Comment: Your link [download source](https://arxiv.org/e-print/2012.11202)  just downloads some unknown file which has 85Kb and cannot be opened.

Comment: @user2925716, the downloaded source is just a text file, `.tex` extension should be added.